# Test-Path in Powershell using data from multiple columns in a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am starting to learn Powershell and I have a csv file (pcfile.csv) with two columns:

- Column one: **PC**    - PC1, PC2, PC3
- Column two: **User**  - John, Michael, Tracy

I want to use test-path to check if the folder exists:

```
\\PC1\c$\users\John  
\\PC2\c$\users\Michael
\\PC3\c$\users\Tracy
```

Here is my code

```
$PCs = import-csv c:\pcfile.csv | select -ExpandProperty PC

$Users = import-csv c:\pcfile.csv | select -ExpandProperty User

Foreach ($PC in $PCs) {

    $Path = Test-Path "\\$PC\c$\$User"

      If ($Path -eq $True) {Write-Host 'Folder exists'}

      Else {Write-Host 'Folder does not exist'}

}
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to put each user from $Users to check the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to treat them as different lists, you just want to reference the different properties.

Sample data for others to be able to assist.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
PC,User
PC1,John
PC2,Michael
PC3,Tracy
'@ | Set-Content $tempfile
```

You want to import the data just once. Then iterate over each line which is made up of a PC property and a User property.

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv $tempfile

foreach($entry in $csvdata){

    If(Test-Path "\\$($entry.pc)\c$\$($entry.user)"){
        Write-Host 'Folder exists'
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host 'Folder does not exist'
    }

}
```

Note that in order to expand the variable and the property inside the path string, we had to enclose it inside of a subexpression `$(...)`. You could also use the format operator.

```
foreach($entry in $csvdata){

    $userpath = "\\{0}\c$\{1}" -f $entry.pc,$entry.user

    If(Test-Path $userpath){
        Write-Host 'Folder exists'
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host 'Folder does not exist'
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, is `{0}{1}` just the place holder for `$entry.pc,$entry.user`? Sorry, just not familiar on how they're used, or when they can be used.

Comment: Thank you very much Doug for the quick response, so I'm not very clear on the $tempfile part, if I have 100 rows of data, do I need to put all the data in the $tempfile block @' PC1, name1 .... up to PC100, name100 '@

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, yes that's right.  Have a look [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)

Comment: @mzoom2021, the $tempfile is just test data for the example.  You instead may change `$csvdata = Import-Csv $tempfile` to `$csvdata = Import-Csv c:\pcfile.csv`

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes the point of the temp file was to have an easy way for others to run the code as well. I recommend you provide that in your next question @mzoom2021. For your actual code you will put in your csv file, not some arbitrary sample file.